# Is 4-momentum conserved during inelastic collision?

Tags: special-relativity, momentum, collision

Both during the case when kinetic energy is transformed to rest mass, and when rest mass is transformed to kinetic energy.

Comment: What kind of inelastic collisions do you have in mind? Can you give an example?

Comment: @SRS perhaps a particle at rest with a greater rest mass decaying into 2 particles, with the sum of their rest masses less than the original particle.

Comment: @SRS I don't think that's important. He's asking for a General Law for These collisions.

Comment: I think it is conserved btw....

Comment: @PhysicsGuy Four-momentum is always conserved unless you have some source of dissipation. That is why I asked what kind of dissipative effect OP has in mind in a relativistic collisions. In classical inelastic collisions, energy goes into heat.

Comment: Even with dissipation the four momentum is conserved. Even in classical mechanics inelastic collisions still conserve energy. The thing they don't conserve is *macroscopic kinetic energy*. I strongly discourage students from saying "inelastic collisions don't conserve energy" or similar phrases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as momentum is conserved in any ordinary collision, elastic or inelastic, so 4-momentum is conserved in any relativistic collision, elastic or inelastic.

Source: https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1011/1011.1943.pdf

Comment: In ordinary inelastic collisions, mechanical energy is not conserved.

Comment: This is true, and is reflected in the above source.

Comment: @SRS But *energy* is still conserved. It's just that some energy enters or leaves the bulk kinetic channel. And the time-like component of the four momentum doesn't care what channel(s) you are talking about.